# Connecting UIKit to Code

Tags: ios, swift, segue, viewcontroller

I have tried to follow the instructions mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html) to connect a UI component to my view controller. Although, whenever I generate the line

```
@IBOutlet weak var mt: UITextView!
```

When I run my app it SIGABRTs after the segue is initiated with the message

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', 
reason: '[<UIViewController 0x10336c400> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mt.'
```

Ive looked through other posts and this can't be dead link because I just created it, and when I delete the referencing outlet, the app doesn't crash anymore.

Can someone please let me know how to fix this? All relevant code is below.

ViewController

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegueID", sender: nil)
...    

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "mySegueID") {
        if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? MessageViewController {
            destinationViewController.message = "Hi friend"
        }
    }
}
```

MessageViewController

```
import UIKit

class MessageViewController: UIViewController {
    var message:String = "default"

    @IBOutlet weak var mt: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mt.text = message
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: 1. Go to the inspector(on right of storyboard/IB) of each viewcontrller and check if you have any referencing outlet by the name of "mt" which is not connected to any iboutlet of that particular view controller

Comment: You haven't set the custom class for your view controller in the storyboard so you are getting a generic `UIViewController`, not your `MessageViewController` - you can see this from the exception message; it references `UIViewController`

Comment: @Paulw11 this is what it looks like, and when you click the grey arrow it takes you to MessageViewController.swift https://imgur.com/a/ETEWl

Comment: @ibnetariq This is what my inspector looks like https://imgur.com/a/1Kcss

Comment: Check for each view controller in your storyboard. My guess is you tried to test few things and left an reference by the name of "mt" in some other controller. https://imgur.com/a/UjHCu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out! What caused the error was the fact that the custom class wasn't recognized. By clicking "Inherit Module from Target", it fixed the problem.

[image]